# Does Bayesian MCMC suffer from local minima?

Tags: bayesian

I am using MCMC to train a model opposed to gradient descent.

Gradient descent suffers from local minima. Is MCMC a global optimization method? That is, are the resulting parameters from training a model with MCMC give us a global minimizer?

Comment: MCMC is not an optimization method at all, it is a method for generating random numbers.  Given this, it is not at all clear to me how you could be using MCMC to train a model.  Are you sure that is what you are doing?

Comment: 1. can you finish your question?
2. Are you asking if MCMC may not sample from the full posterior distribution? (that's not really a local minima)

Comment: @Memming I'm training a Bayesian neural net

Comment: @jbow see above.

Comment: To add to jbowmans comment: mcmc is not optimization. It can be used to sample from a posterior, and using that sample construct an estimate. Gd and mcmc are similar only that they produce estimates. But  there is no minimum for mcmc.

Comment: @jbowman agree, yet MCMC chains can got "stuck" on some range of values of the simulated distribution, so this can be thought as a kind of local minimum problem.

Comment: @Tim - yes, but the questions as asked by the OP are "Is MCMC a global optimization method?" and "... give us a global minimizer?"  The answer to both questions is "No, MCMC is not an optimization method at all."

Comment: MCMC can be used as an optimization method; it is ignorant comment to state that it is not

Comment: Markov Chains can be used in optimization problems. I invite you to educate yourselves on Markov Chains and Simulated Annealing.